# LNK1169 "one or more multiply defined symbols found" in a basic game

Tags: c++, project

This project is not done but currently my group is stuck with the LNK1169 error.

We have a player.h and player.cpp as well as an enemy.h and enemy.cpp and obviously a source.cpp.  Somehow the linking between the files got messed up when we combined work on the player and work on the enemy files.

Source.cpp

```
//#pragma once

#include "Player.h"
#include "Enemy.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Welcome to our game" << endl;
cout << endl << endl << endl;

int ans = 0;

do {
    cout << "    Main Menu" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "1:     Play Game" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "2:     Exit" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;

    cin >> ans;

    switch (ans)
    {
    case 1: //main body of game

    case 2:
        return 0;

    default:
        cout << "Please enter 1 to play the game or 2 to exit" << endl;
        cin >> ans;
        break;
    }
} while (ans != 2);
return 0;
}
```

Enemy.h:

```
/*           UML
           Enemies
******************************************
Private
- Health: int
- Attack : int
- Defence : int
******************************************
Public
+ accessor and mutator functions
+ AttackCharacter()
+ DefendCharacter()
+ ChangePosition()
+ LoseHealth()
+ RandomSpawn()
*******************************************
*/
//#pragma once
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Enemy
{
private:
    int
        health,
        attack,
        defence;

public:
    Enemy(int Health, int Attack, int Defence)
    {
        health = Health; attack = Attack; defence = Defence;
    }

    int getHealth();
    int getAttack();
    int getDefence();

    void setHealth(int h);
    void setAttack(int a);
    void setDefence(int d);

    //void Attack(Player P1);
};

#endif
```

Enemy.cpp

```
#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Player.h"

/*#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
*/

int Enemy::getHealth() { return health; }
int Enemy::getAttack() { return attack; }
int Enemy::getDefence() { return defence; }

void Enemy::setHealth(int h)
{
    health = h;
}

void Enemy::setAttack(int a)
{
    attack = a;
}

void Enemy::setDefence(int d)
{
    defence = d;
}

//void Enemy::Attack(Player P1)
//{
//  int h = P1.getHealth();
//  int d = P1.getDefence();
//  int a = getAttack();
//  if (d + h - a > h)
//  {
//      cout << "You lost 0 health" << endl;
//      P1.setHealth(h);
//  }
//  else
//  {
//      int h1 = h + d - a;
//      cout << "You lost " << h1 - h << " health" << endl;
//      P1.setHealth(h1);
//  }
//}
```

The Enemy::attack() function is a work in progress and not really the problem

Player.h:

```
//#pragma once
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Armor
{
    string name;
    char type;
    int health;
    int attack;
    int defense;
    Armor() { name = ""; type = ' '; health = 0; attack = 0; defense = 0; } //  constructor
};

struct Weapon
{
    string name;
    char type;
    int health;
    int attack;
    int defense;
    Weapon() { name = ""; type = ' '; health = 0; attack = 0; defense = 0; } //  constructor
};

struct Shield
{
    string name;
    char type;
    int health;
    int attack;
    int defense;
    Shield() { name = ""; type = ' '; health = 0; attack = 0; defense = 0; } //  constructor
};

struct Potion
{
    string name;
    char type;
    int health;
    int attack;
    int defense;
    Potion() { name = ""; type = ' '; health = 0; attack = 0; defense = 0; } //  constructor
};

vector<string> type = { "Bronze", "Iron", "Silver", "Steel", "Gold", "Diamond" };

class Player
{
private:
    string name;
    int initialhealth;
    int initialattack;
    int initialdefense;
    int health;
    int attack;
    int defense;
public:
    Player(string n = " ", int ih = 0, int ia = 0, int id = 0, int h = 0, int a = 0, int d = 0)
    {
        name = n; initialhealth = ih; initialattack = ia; initialdefense = id; health = h; attack = a; defense = d;
    };

    Armor armor;
    Weapon weapon;
    Shield shield;
    Potion potion;

    string getname();
    int getinitialhealth();
    int getinitialattack();
    int getinitialdefense();
    int getHealth();
    int getAttack();
    int getDefense();

    void setname(string n);
    void setinitialhealth(int ih);
    void setinitialattack(int ia);
    void setinitialdefense(int id);
    void setHealth(int h);
    void setAttack(int a);
    void setDefense(int d);

    void addITEMS();
    void displayPlayer();
    void checkARMOR();

};


#endif
```

Player.cpp:

```
//#include <iostream>
//#include <string>
#include "Player.h"
//using namespace std;

string Player::getname() { return name; }
int Player::getinitialhealth() { return initialhealth; }
int Player::getinitialattack() { return initialattack; }
int Player::getinitialdefense() { return initialdefense; }
int Player::getHealth() { return health; }
int Player::getAttack() { return attack; }
int Player::getDefense() { return defense; }

void Player::setname(string n) { name = n; }
void Player::setinitialhealth(int ih) { initialhealth = ih; }
void Player::setinitialattack(int ia) { initialattack = ia; }
void Player::setinitialdefense(int id) { initialdefense = id; }
void Player::setHealth(int ih) { health = ih; }
void Player::setAttack(int ia) { attack = ia; }
void Player::setDefense(int id) { defense = id; }

void Player::addITEMS()
{
    health = initialhealth + armor.health + weapon.health + shield.health;
    attack = initialattack + armor.attack + weapon.attack + shield.attack;
    defense = initialdefense + armor.defense + weapon.defense + shield.defense;
}

void Player::displayPlayer()
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "=========================" << endl;
    cout << " Name    : " << name << endl;
    cout << " Health  : " << health << endl;
    cout << " Attack  : " << attack << endl;
    cout << " Defence : " << defense << endl;
    cout << "=========================" << endl;
}


void Player::checkARMOR()
{
    if (weapon.name == "Bronze")
    {
        armor.health = 10;
        armor.attack = 5;
        armor.defense = 15;
    }

    if (armor.name == "Iron")
    {
        armor.health = 100;
        armor.attack = 15;
        armor.defense = 150;
    }
}
```

Any insight anyone could give into why the LNK1169 error may be popping up would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: The error message means that you've defined (at least) one function more than once. Without more information (e.g., the full compiler output, which should include which functions are defined multiple times), it's not possible to provide much more help. Also, for future reference, make sure to reduce your examples to the shortest possible segment necessary to reproduce the problem. This is just a code dump.

Answer (score 2):

Its simple, you have used

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
```

twice in Player.h and Enemy.h. Just simply replace:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
```

by

```
#ifndef ENEMY_H
#define ENEMY_H
```

in Enemy.h

Or use `#pragma once` preprocessor directive before your declarations in *.h
 files

But the real problem is this line in Player.h

```
std::vector<std::string> type = { "Bronze", "Iron", "Silver", "Steel", "Gold", "Diamond" };
```

To declare an global variable in a header use the keyword extern.

```
// Player.h
extern std::vector<std::string> type;

// Player.cpp
std::vector<std::string> type = { "Bronze", "Iron", "Silver", "Steel", "Gold", "Diamond" };
```

Is it not an option to change this to an enum class?

```
enum class Types {
    Bronze,
    Iron,
    Silver,
    Steel,
    Gold,
    Diamond
};
```

And use namespace through out the application?